# Asynchronous JSON Requests in Python

Tags: python, json, http, asynchronous, python-requests

I'm using an API for doing HTTP requests that return JSON. The calling of the api, however, depends on a start and an end page to be indicated, such as this:

```
def API_request(URL):
    while(True):
        try:
            Response = requests.get(URL)
            Data = Response.json()
            return(Data['data'])
        except Exception as APIError:
            print(APIError)
            continue
        break
def build_orglist(start_page, end_page):
    APILink = ("http://sc-api.com/?api_source=live&system=organizations&action="
               "all_organizations&source=rsi&start_page={0}&end_page={1}&items_"
               "per_page=500&sort_method=&sort_direction=ascending&expedite=1&f"
               "ormat=json".format(start_page, end_page))
    return(API_request(APILink))
```

The only way to know if you're not longer at an existing page is when the JSON will be null, like [this](http://sc-api.com/?api_source=live&start_date=&end_date=&system=organizations&action=all_organizations&source=rsi&target_id=&start_page=99999&end_page=99999&items_per_page=255&sort_method=&sort_direction=ascending&expedite=1&location=redirect&format=json).

If I wanted to do multiple `build_orglist` going over every single page asynchronously until I reach the end (Null JSON) how could I do so?

Comment: Take a look into Python multiprocessing: http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/python-multiprocessing-as-a-task-queue.html

Comment: @AlexReynolds I have had a quick look at multiprocessing before, what truly bugs me is that I just can't make a logic for this. I've never worked with parallelism before, and it's proving itself a bit challenging. I just can't formulate the logic for this in my head most of the time.

Comment: theres `asyncio` in python 3, Tornado: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ and other async libs...

Comment: @riotburn I hadn't seen Tornado before, thanks! The problem here is more logical than about resources. I'm having some trouble thinking of a way to make things stop once my responses are `None`. Because since it's asynchronous how will I iterate over a number of pages and implement a way to make it stop once all `n` workers get a `None`, or terminate one worker at a time as they receive `None`s

Comment: @Arengorn are you looking to use parallelism in order to increase performance? If so, first make sure you're using [sessions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects)! This will give you persistent HTTP connections, and therefore a massive performance boost for repeated requests to the same host.

Comment: @LukasGraf, Indeed I was doing this whole thing because I need to do A LOT of requests and it was being rather slow, so I figured parallelism was the way to go. I had no idea about sessions! I'll try it out right now and check out the results, Thanks!

Comment: @LukasGraf, It did make a performance difference, however that was small. If I were able to get both async requests with Sessions together it will probably become very noticeable. My implementation: http://pastebin.com/KcVJxhyE

Comment: @Arengorn did you make sure to only instantiate the session once? With [this example](https://gist.github.com/lukasgraf/16c6db9dd9aaea1c2456), I already get a performance increase of 4x. And that's a rather "bad" example, because fetching Wikipedia articles actually means transferring a lot of data - with smaller payloads like JSON, the gains should be even more pronounced.

Comment: @LukasGraf, I ran both funtions, with and without sessions, side by side. Here is [code for both](https://gist.github.com/Arengorn/3870d1533f68b0930115) and here is the [terminal output](https://gist.github.com/Arengorn/481d9a9eafaa6c058122) showing the performance difference. It really is weird though, maybe it's the fact that the API request is for getting data from another website so it won't change so much after all.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm noticing you're not passing the `session` to your `build_orglist` function - are you not making any requests in that function any more?

Comment: My bad, forgot to mention, I altered that a little bit, on the Sessions code it only returns a formatted URL instead of actually doing the request.(`do_query` parameter)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93543/discussion-between-lukas-graf-and-arengorn).

Comment: @LukasGraf, I might need that extra help we had discussed :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a mix of @LukasGraf's answer of using sessions to unify all of my HTTP connections into a single session as well as made use of [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) for making the group of HTTP requests in parallel.